# Canvas in different shapes with fabricjs plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to set canvas shape to circle and any other on click of button . but normal clip is not working with fabricjs . can you please share simple canvas shape example for my reference ?

i am using fabricjs , i tried below code and many more but nothing worked .

```
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
     // clip to a circle circle
     ctx.rect(10,20,300,200);
     ctx.stroke();
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope will help you.

```
<select name="Decal Shape" id="decalshap" class="hasClass" style="height:30px;">
<option > Select Shape </option>
<option value="oval"> OVAL </option>
<option value="circle"> CIRCLE </option>
<option value="rectangle">RECTANGLE</option>
<option value="hrectangle"> HORIZONTAL RECTANGLE </option>
<option value="vrectangle"> VERTICAL RECTANGLE </option>
</select>
<div id="work_area">
</div>

    $("#decalshap").change(function() {
         alert("decal");
         var shap = $(this).val();
     if(shap=="oval")
        {
         var elementID = 'canvas' + $('canvas').length;
         $('<canvas>').attr({
        id: elementID
    }).css({
        width:1200,
        height:600
    }).appendTo('#work_area');
     var canvas = document.getElementById(elementID);
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   // ctx.fillStyle='rgba(70, 70, 255, 0.7)'
   // ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);
    var centerX = 0;
      var centerY = 0;
      var radius = 50;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      ctx.scale(2, 1);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.restore();
      ctx.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    }  
    if(shap=="circle")
        {
          var elementID = 'canvas' + $('canvas').length;
         $('<canvas>').attr({
        id: elementID
    }).css({
        width:1200,
        height:600
    }).appendTo('#work_area');
    var canvas = document.getElementById(elementID);
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
       }
       if(shap=="hrectangle")
        {
        var elementID = 'canvas' + $('canvas').length;
         $('<canvas>').attr({
        id: elementID
    }).css({
        width:1200,
        height:300
    }).appendTo('#work_area');
    var canvas = document.getElementById(elementID);
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.fillStyle='border: 1px dotted';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,400);
       }
       if(shap=="vrectangle")
        {
          var elementID = 'canvas' + $('canvas').length;
         $('<canvas>').attr({
        id: elementID
    }).css({
        width:300,
        height:600
    }).appendTo('#work_area');
    var canvas = document.getElementById(elementID);
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.fillStyle='border: 1px dotted';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,200);
       }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this script to convert your Canvas in circle shapes with fabricjs.You can clip your canvas to any shape using `clipTo` function as i clip my canvas in circle shape

//html

```
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

//script

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.backgroundColor = 'red';
var w=canvas.width / 2;
var h=canvas.height / 2;
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {

 //ctx.scale(2, 1);
ctx.arc(w, h, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2,true);

};
 canvas.renderAll();
var text;
text = new fabric.Text('Honey', {
  fontSize: 50,
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  lineHeight: 1,
  originX: 'left',
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fontWeight: 'bold'
});
canvas.add(text);
```

//css

```
canvas {  border:1px solid #000;     }
.controles {  margin:50px 0;   }
```

Here is my [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xadqg/5/) hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?