# How can I create an irregularly shaped HTML Canvas using FabricJS?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I've been attempting to create a triangle shaped canvas for a day or so now and I'm having no luck. The canvas is always square/rectangle. I'm using FabricJS but I can also manipulate the canvas directly if that's an option.

I've attempted using .clipTo(ctx) to clip the canvas as described here: [Canvas in different shapes with fabricjs plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976981/canvas-in-different-shapes-with-fabricjs-plugin)

I've also attempted manipulating the canvas directly as I saw here: https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-custom-shapes/

What I'm trying to accomplish is for a user to drag-drop images onto a triangle shaped canvas so there's no "bleed" of the image outside the triangle shape. I accomplished this easily with a rectangle but I can't figure out how to change the canvas shape. OR if anyone has a "trick" solution that would look like the canvas was a triangle but under the hood remain a square, that would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using pure API's

I don't use fabric (especially if its just for simple image manipulation) so you will have to locate the appropriate [fabric functions](http://fabricjs.com/docs/) to match this answer.

The canvas is always 4 sided. 2D and 3D transforms can change the shape but that also changes the shape of the contained pixels.

You have 2 simple options. There are other ways to do this but they are complex and have compatibility issues.

### Visual only

#### Masking

To get the appearance of irregular shaped canvas you can use a mask (second canvas has mask). Draw the content to the main canvas and then mask that canvas with the mask.

Use the property [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) to define how the mask is applied.

eg

```
function createTriangleMask(w, h) {
    const mask = document.createElement("canvas");
    mask.width = w;
    mask.height = h;
    mask.ctx = mask.getContext("2d");
    mask.ctx.beginPath();
    mask.ctx.lineTo(w / 2, 0);
    mask.ctx.lineTo(w    , h);
    mask.ctx.lineTo(0    , h);
    mask.ctx.fill();
    return mask;
}
const mask = createTriangleMask(ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); 
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
ctx.drawImage(mask, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);  
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

#### Using 2D [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip)

Or you can use the 2D API [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip) to create a clip region and draw the content while the clip is active. Don't forget to pop the 2D state when done with the clip,

```
function triangleClip(ctx, w, h) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    mask.ctx.lineTo(w / 2, 0);
    mask.ctx.lineTo(w    , h);
    mask.ctx.lineTo(0    , h);
    ctx.clip();
}

triangleClip(ctx, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); 
ctx.restore(); // Turn off clip. Must do before calling triangle clip again.
```

### Still rectangular!

This has not changed the canvas shape. It is still a rectangle, just that some pixels are transparent. The DOM still sees a rectangle and user interactions with the canvas will still use the whole rectangular canvas.

#### CSS [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

You can use the style property [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to define the shape of a element. This will clip the elements visual content and the elements interactive area. Effectively turning any applicable element to an irregular shaped element.

Using JS Declarative

```
canvas.style.clipPath = "polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)"
```

Using JS

```
function clipElement(el, shape) {
    var rule = "polygon(", i = 0, comma = "";
    while (i < shape.length) { 
        rule += comma + shape[i++] + "% " + shape[i++] + "%";
        comma = ",";
    }
    el.style.clipPath = rule + ")";
}

clipElement(canvas, [50, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100]);
```

Using CSS rule

```
canvas {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

With the clipped path in place the canvas will obey its shape via UI

```
canvas.style.cursor = "pointer";  // Pointer change only inside clipped area
canvas.title = "foo"; // appears only when over clipped area
canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", () => console.log("foo")); // fires when crossing
                                                                // clip boundary
```

### Demo

Creates an animated clip via JS on the canvas element with content rendered once.

There are limitations

- **Note** that the CSS defined background color (yellow) and shadow are also clipped. Many other visual properties will also be clipped.
- **Note** that JS animation does not update UI events if there are no intervening user iteration.
- The animation can also be achieved via CSS.
- Compatibility with fabric is unknown to me, check their [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/).

```js
var clearConsole = 0;
const s = 2 ** 0.5 * 0.25, clipPath = [0.5, 0, 0.5 + s, 0.5 + s,  0.5 - s, 0.5 + s], img = new Image;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1";
img.addEventListener("load",() => canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300), {once: true});

requestAnimationFrame(animateLoop);
function clipRotate(el, ang, scale, path) {
    const dx = Math.cos(ang) * scale;
    const dy = Math.sin(ang) * scale;
    var clip = "polygon(", i = 0, comma = "";
    while (i < path.length) {
        const x = path[i++] - 0.5;
        const y = path[i++] - 0.5;
        clip += comma;
        clip += ((x * dx - y * dy + 0.5) * 100) + "% ";
        clip += ((x * dy + y * dx + 0.5) * 100) + "%";
        comma = ",";
    }
    el.style.clipPath = clip + ")";    
}

function animateLoop(time) {
    clipRotate(canvas, time / 1000 * Math.PI, 0.9, clipPath);
    requestAnimationFrame(animateLoop);
    if (clearConsole) {
       clearConsole --;
       !clearConsole && console.clear();
    }
}

canvas.addEventListener("pointerenter", () => (clearConsole = 30, console.log("Pointer over")));
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #49C;
}
canvas {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 12px 12px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" title="You are over the clipped canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the examples! Still playing with a few of these with Fabric before I flag as the answer.